# How to select the next table's row clicking a checkbox

Tags: jquery, html-table, css-selectors, row

Here the HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Customer Reviews
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="p_reviews" /> (checkbox that trigger action)
    </td>
</tr>
<tr> (row to select)
    <td>
        How many reviews do you want to display?
    </td>
    <td>
    ...
    </td>
</tr>
```

And here the javascript:

```
$("form[name='myform'] input[name='p_reviews']").click(function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(this).closest('tr').next().show();
} else{
    $(this).closest('tr').next().hide();
}
});
```

This is not working. Any tip?

**EDIT**: Sorry folks, Yes, it is working. Just was a HTML double-quote missing!

Comment: It appears to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/AKc7D/

Comment: Assuming your selector is correct, and the DOM is ready when this code executes, what you have should work: http://jsfiddle.net/XGPt9/4/

Comment: Sorry folks, Yes, it is working. Just was a HTML double-quote missing! Thanks to all...

Comment: You should consider using CSS classes or even IDs to make it easier to select the element.

Comment: @stefan The idea is exactly the opposite. Don't use too many IDs or Classes. Am I a bad Guy? 8)

Comment: The selector `form[name='myform'] input[name='p_reviews']` just seems a bit overhead, perfomance wise.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('form[name="myform"] input[name="p_reviews"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').show();
    } else{
        $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').next('tr').toggle(this.checked);` might be something? :)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you run that code on document ready. And also you can just use `this.checked`. Try this

```
$(function(){
  $("form[name='myform'] input[name='p_reviews']").click(function() {
     if (this.checked){
         $(this).closest('tr').next().show();
     } else{
         $(this).closest('tr').next().hide();
     }
  });
});
```

Alternatively you can use toggle which is much simpler.

```
    $(function(){
      $("form[name='myform'] input[name='p_reviews']").click(function() {
         $(this).closest('tr').next().toggle(this.checked);
      });
    });
```

Comment: He could use `toggle()` as well.

Comment: @stefan Yes, `toggle()` is useful here (I have more code in the inner blocks).

Comment: @NomikOS - toggle will reduce your code if this logic is used at many places.